# Using typing with vargs

Tags: python-3.x

What is the suggested way to deal with something like this, where a user may pass arguments to it that the function doesn't necessarily know about beforehand:

```
def __call__(self, x: str, *args: ?, **kwargs: ?):
    # do something here
```

Is don't see any examples on the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) does as to how this should be done so am curious, or if it's best just to not type-annotate it at all.

Comment: Are the varargs of the same type, or different types within a single call? Is there any sure information about the types? Are the types consistent across calls on the same object?

Comment: Worst case, you can just make it `typing.Any`. Do you have more information to go on?